Integrability implies piecewise continuity
Is it correct to say that if a function is Riemann-integrable, then it is piecewise continuous (note the "piecewise") ? I have found sufficient conditions for integrability such as continuity, piecewise continuity, etc but what about necessary conditions ?
My intuition is that my title statement is wrong, counterexample is $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is not piecewise continuous yet Riemann-integrable but can we find something close ?

Take Thomae's function on $[0,1]$, which is discontinuous at all rationals on that interval but is still Riemann integrable.

@J.D Yes, I guess so (see my counterexample) but what about saying "if f is Riemann-integrable and [mild condition I am looking for], then it's piecewise continuous" ?

Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions to convey important information and please don't refer to the title in the body of your question. The body should be self-contained.  As regards the mathematics, what domain are you looking at? $\sin(1/x)$ is continuous on any subset of the real line that excludes $0$ and isn't defined at $0$, so it doesn't seem to be relevant.

$\sin(1/x)$ is a continuous function. It's a common misconception, when we say that a function $f$ is "continuous" we mean that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = f(x_0)$$
for each $x_0 \in \mathrm{Dom}\,f$. This is precisely the case. $0$ is not in the domain of the function, so it doesn't even make sense to talk about continuity at that point.
We often speak of "continuous extension" of a function like this one at a point $x=x_0$. That just means considering a new function, $\hat f(x)$ having domain $\mathrm{Dom}\,f\cup\{x_0\}$ and being continuous at $x=x_0$. Here this is possible, since the function $\hat f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined as
$$\hat f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin x}x,&x\ne0\\1,&x=0\end{cases}$$
is continuous, differentiable and its domain is the whole $\Bbb R$, which is pretty nice. Behold, this does not mean that the function $f$ is not continuous.

A correct counterexample has been given in the comments: Thomae's function's domain is $\mathbb R$ and it has an infinite number of discontinuities within such domain; to be precise, this function is not continuous at any rational number. The proof is fairly simple. It is also Riemann integrable, since the set of the discontinuities is $\mathbb Q$, which has Lebesgue measure equal to zero (the integral will always be $0$, of course, for the support of the function is also a null set).

"A continuous function can have discontinuities" - You're using one of those words in a sense I'm not used to. I'm not sure which, but it might even be "have".

@JonathanZ the definition of discontinuity can slightly vary based on who you're asking to. I have seen people call a removable discontinuity a point where the function is not defined, but that, if defined, would make the function continuous. Others prefer to speak of discontinuities only within the domain of the function. Personally, I prefer the former, but it's only a matter of definition really.

I think there's a strong preference here for a function to have an associated domain, and if you enlarge the domain you've created a different/new function. The reason for that is it reduces the potential for confusion. I can see that people may use other conventions, but telling students "a continuous function can have discontinuities" seems ripe for causing confusion, so I personally would never say that.

@JonathanZ yeah, that is true. However, even when we speak of removable discontinuities within the domain of the function, in order for the function to be made continuous we still have to modify it. By the way, I agree that it's not a good terminology from a pedagogical standpoint.

The convention I'm used to is that when we modify a function we have a different function. That does sometimes conflict with people who have been treating a "mathematical expression" as defining a function, and not bothering with any details about the domain, but at some point the get the "we've reached the level of math where start getting explicit about function domains" talk.

Which is all to say that I think your answer would be better without that sentence. No shade on you if you reconsider it but decide it still belongs, but that's the explanation for my downvote.

@JonathanZ no, I agree with you and I was not suggesting that you can change the domain of a function without changing the function as a mathematical object, which is obviously false. They are objectively different functions, and there is an important distinction to be made between a function and the expression that describes it. The only reason why I didn't edit the answer yet is that I'm typing from my phone right now, which is annoying, so I will remove that sentence or add a clarification later.

Ugh, phone editing.  And I'll check back later - I can't reverse my vote until there has been an edit.

@JonathanZ edit made. I added a bit about continuous extensions, because I've seen some confusion around the concept of "making a function that is already continuous continuous" (of course that's not what we're doing, but I've read that sentence pretty much verbatim not long ago.)

Nice. And thanks for pinging me.
